# self-indexing numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Problem: Given N, return an NxN matrix whose i,jth entry is (i,j)

I have decided to solve this problem using numpy by creating matrices

```
A=    0, 0, 0
      1, 1, 1
      2, 2, 2
```

and

```
B=    0, 1, 2
      0, 1, 2
      0, 1, 2
```

I would now like a method that takes numpy arrays of the same shape and returns the element-wise zip. Obviously you can do this with a for loop over NxN, but id rather not do that. Here is my specific question: is there a method SomeKindOfZip(,) so that

```
SomeKindOfZip(A,B) =     (0,0), (0,1), (0,2)
                         (1,0), (1,1), (1,2)
                         (2,0), (2,1), (2,2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways.  Using `meshgrid` to make the 2 array:

```
In [20]: I,J=np.meshgrid([0,1,2],[0,1,2,3], indexing='ij')
In [21]: I
Out[21]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2]])
In [22]: J
Out[22]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

And `stack` to join them on a new trailing axis:

```
In [23]: np.stack((I,J),axis=2)
Out[23]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2],
        [0, 3]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 3]],

       [[2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [2, 3]]])
```

Your display looks like a (3,3) object dtype array containing tuples.  Object dtype arrays more like lists than arrays.  I suppose it could also be a structured arrays.  It all depends how you intend to use the result.